# Twilio: say message to User if the "number" inside <dial> verb is not "completed"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am placing an outbound call from my application.

```
def connect_outbound_call
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial callerId: TWILIO_VOICE_NUMBER do |d|
      d.Number params["phone_number"]
    end
  end
  render text: response.text
end
```

Now my requirement is, if the `params["phone_number"]` is busy or not answering i.e. call-status value is not `"completed"`, I would like to play a message to User as
`"Couldn't reach <user name> try again soon. Goodbye."`

Above as am calling another number, its logged as a child-call, so if that inside call is not completed, just play message.

Its may be something like of having some timeout, and when timeout is reached just play message.(along with handling busy states etc.)

Can anyone please give me hints or approach to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely do that. You'll need to set an `action` attribute on the `<Dial>` verb that points to another TwiML endpoint.

When the call completes, Twilio will then make a request to that endpoint, sending in [some parameters regarding the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial%23attributes-action-parameters).

The attribute you're interested in is the `DialCallStatus`. If the call was answered and continued as normal, it will be 'completed' otherwise there are 4 other [ways the call ended](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial%23attributes-action-dial-call-status-values) which you can check for and return the TwiML to `<Say>` a message instead.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I have tried adding `action` in `<dial>` verb, but that was getting called when the caller is ending his call. and not when the number am calling is stop ringing (not answering).

Comment: You can add a `timeout` attribute to the `<Dial>` verb too, which will move on to the `action` when it's up.

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck with the rest of the app.

Comment: hello, please is there a way to detect that  the *called* party picked up (answered) when using [Dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) without having to wait for the end of the call (without relying on [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action))

Comment: @Scaramouche Yep, use a `<Number>` within `<Dial>` and the [`statusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback). That will send you a webhook when the call is [initiated, ringing, answered and completed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event).